# Salesforce DX and Heroku CI

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, heroku, continuous-integration, development-mode

I have discovered Salesforce DX and done some test using its.

I have also read about Heroku CI and Pipelines but I have not understood if I can use these technologies during Salesforce DX development.

For example, I have found some example using NodeJs and Heroku CI/Pipelines but nothing about Salesforce DX.

Is it possible or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a heroku buildpack to support the integration and run DX with Heroku Pipelines  .The buildpack can be deployed to Heroku instance .

The git repo has more details

https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-buildpack

Comment: Thanks, Mohith! Do you know any blogs, articles or documents to explain how use buildpack?

Comment: The instructions are only on git repo read me .I will see if i can find any more details .